# Ember link-to throws error / does not clear screen as expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-app-kit

having some trouble getting my ember routing to work, and I'm a bit confused if I am doing it right. Seems like there has been quite a few changes to this part, which can be a bit confusing. I hope someone can help me see what is going wrong here.

### Application

refset.sparklingideas.co.uk:8000

### Environment

Cloned Ember App Kit on Nov. 20th, 2013

```
Ember       : 1.2.0-beta.4
Ember Data  : 1.0.0-beta.2
Handlebars  : 1.1.2
Query       : 1.9.1

Node        : v0.10.21
Chrome      : 31.0.1650.16 beta
OS X        : Maverick
```

All source code is available here:
https://github.com/sparkling/snomed-refset

Sorry, no luck in getting it hosted yet, but I do have screenshots to illustrate:
http://goo.gl/DGBSvf

### Problem

I am having two problems with my current configuration.

1. When clicking on a link-to to return to the main screen (/, "refsets"), the contents of the child screen (/:publicid) gets prepended to the bottom of the main screen. This keeps stacking up as you navigate back and forth.
2. When clicking on the link-to for the buttons "show rules" or "show concepts", the screen goes blank, and ember returns this cryptic error (other custom and ember logging details provided, too):

   ```
   Loading concepts in router ember.js:3227
   GETing concepts for: {...} ember.js:3227

   Rendering refset.concepts with default view <appkit@view:default::ember404> 
   Object {fullName: "view:refset.concepts"} ember.js:3227

   Transitioned into 'refset.concepts' ember.js:3227

   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null ember.js:24102

   Assertion failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and 
   should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug 
   in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications. 
   ember.js:3227

   Uncaught Error: You cannot modify child views while in the inBuffer state 
   ember.js:22892
   ```

These problematic 'link-to' statements are located:

1. in 'template/refset.hbs' (breadcrumbs, top): causes content to stack
2. in 'template/refset/concept.hbs' and 'template/refset/plan.hbs'(heading, top): causes ember error

Source can be found at link above, and also copied in below.

### Source

#### Route

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend();

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('refsets', {path:'/'});
  this.resource('create',  {path:'/create'}, function(){});
  this.resource('refset',  {path:'/:publicId'}, function(){
    this.route('concepts',  {path:'/'});
    this.route('plan',  {path:'plan'});
  });
});

Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});

export default Router;
```

#### template/refset/concepts.hbs

```
<secion id="concepts">
  <h2>Concepts
  {{#link-to 'refset.plan' refset}}<button class="toggle btn btn-sm btn-default">Show Rules</button>{{/link-to}}
  </h2>
  <table id="forums" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Effective on</th>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each concept in controller}}
      <tr>
        <td><a {{bind-attr href=concept.href}} target="_blank">{{concept.title}}</a></td>
        <td>{{concept.id}}</td>
        <td>{{date-format concept.effectiveTime}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>^0k334q5PK3Wcn#p^4CS#
```

#### template/refset/plan.hbs

```
<secion id="plan">
  <h2>Plan
  {{#link-to 'refset.concepts' refset}}<button class="toggle btn btn-sm btn-default">Show Concepts</button>{{/link-to}}
  </h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
  {{#each rule in rules}}
    <li class="list-group-item">
    {{show-rule rule}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <div class="terminal">Terminal: {{terminal}}</div>
</section>
```

#### template/refset.hbs

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li>{{#link-to 'refsets'}}Refsets{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li class="active">{{title}}</li>
</ol>

<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<section id="details">
{{outlet details}}
<section id="details">
```

#### controllers/refset/concepts.js

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  conceptsResponse: 'concepts-response-not-set',
  needs: "refset",
  refset: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.refset.model")
});
```

#### controllers/refset/plan.js

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  planResponse: 'plan-response-not-set',
  needs: "refset",
  refset: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.refset")
});
```

#### controllers/refset.js

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

#### routes/refset/concepts.js

```
import Refset from 'appkit/models/refset';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    Ember.Logger.log('Loading concepts in router');
    return Refset.getConcepts(this.modelFor('refset'), this);
  },
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render({outlet:'details'});
  }
});
```

#### routes/refset/plan.js

```
import Refset from 'appkit/models/refset';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    Ember.Logger.log('Loading plan in router');
    return Refset.getPlan(this.modelFor('refset'), this);
  },
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render({outlet:'details'});
  }  
});
```

#### routes/refset.js

```
import Refset from 'appkit/models/refset';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(args) {
    return Refset.loadRefset(args.publicId, this);
  }
});
```

### JSON AJAX Response

#### Plan/Rules

```
{
  "id":25,
  "terminal":67,
  "rules":[
    {
      "id":65,
      "type":"LIST",
      "left":null,
      "right":null,
      "concepts":[
        {
          "id":321987003,
          "title":"Citalopram 20mg tablet (product)",
          "active":false,
          "effectiveTime":0
        },
        {
          "id":441519008,
          "title":"Contusion of infraorbital nerve (disorder)",
          "active":false,
          "effectiveTime":0
        },
        {
          "id":17783003,
          "title":"Car sickness (finding)",
          "active":false,
          "effectiveTime":0
        },
        {
          "id":128665000,
          "title":"Pituitary carcinoma (morphologic abnormality)",
          "active":false,
          "effectiveTime":0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":66,
      "type":"LIST",
      "left":null,
      "right":null,
      "concepts":[
        {
          "id":254597002,
          "title":"Oleogranuloma of intestine (disorder)",
          "active":false,
          "effectiveTime":0
        },
        {
          "id":412398008,
          "title":"Griseofulvin microsize (product)",
          "active":false,
          "effectiveTime":0
        },
        {
          "id":118831003,
          "title":"Procedure on intestine (procedure)",
          "active":false,
          "effectiveTime":0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":67,
      "type":"UNION",
      "left":65,
      "right":66,
      "concepts":[

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Concepts

```
{
  "concepts":[
    {
      "id":321987003,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/321987003",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Citalopram 20mg tablet (product)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    },
    {
      "id":441519008,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/441519008",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Contusion of infraorbital nerve (disorder)",
      "effectiveTime":20090731,
      "active":true
    },
    {
      "id":17783003,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/17783003",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Car sickness (finding)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    },
    {
      "id":128665000,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/128665000",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Pituitary carcinoma (morphologic abnormality)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    },
    {
      "id":254597002,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/254597002",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Oleogranuloma of intestine (disorder)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    },
    {
      "id":412398008,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/412398008",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Griseofulvin microsize (product)",
      "effectiveTime":20040731,
      "active":true
    },
    {
      "id":118831003,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/118831003",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Procedure on intestine (procedure)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Refsets

```
[
  {
    "id":41,
    "concept":{
      "id":2189000,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/2189000",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Hemoglobin F-Dammam (substance)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    },
    "publicId":"ffff",
    "title":"fffff",
    "description":"ffffff",
    "created":"2013-11-24",
    "lastModified":"2013-11-24"
  },
  {
    "id":44,
    "concept":{
      "id":27089009,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/27089009",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Blood group antibody Ce (substance)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    },
    "publicId":"qqqqqqqqqqq",
    "title":"qqqqqqq",
    "description":"qqqqqqq",
    "created":"2013-11-25",
    "lastModified":"2013-11-25"
  },
  {
    "id":23,
    "concept":{
      "id":21304000,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/21304000",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Hemoglobin A,c (substance)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":false
    },
    "publicId":"sdsdawaesf",
    "title":"sdsdsdsd",
    "description":"sdsdsdsd",
    "created":"2013-10-10",
    "lastModified":"2013-10-10"
  },
  {
    "id":21,
    "concept":{
      "id":2156000,
      "href":"http://browser.snomedtools.com/version/1/concept/xml/2156000",
      "serialisedId":0,
      "title":"Glial cell (cell)",
      "effectiveTime":20020131,
      "active":true
    },
    "publicId":"heyho",
    "title":"This is a sample refset",
    "description":"and I am a sample description",
    "created":"2013-10-09",
    "lastModified":"2013-10-09"
  }
]
```

### Helpers

#### show-rule

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(rule) {
  if (rule.get('type') === 'LIST'){
    return new window.Handlebars.SafeString("<span style=\"color: lightgrey\">" + rule.get('id') + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>List</strong> <span style=\"padding-left: 0.5em;color:grey\">[" + rule.get('concepts').length + "]</span>");
  }
  else if (rule.get('type') === 'UNION'){
    return new window.Handlebars.SafeString("<span style=\"color: lightgrey\">" + rule.get('id') + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong></strong>Rule " + rule.get('left') + " <strong>Union</strong> Rule " + rule.get('right'));
  }
  else if (rule.get('type') === 'DIFFERENCE'){
    return new window.Handlebars.SafeString("<span style=\"color: lightgrey\">" + rule.get('id') + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong></strong>Rule " + rule.get('left') + " <strong>Difference</strong> Rule " + rule.get('right'));
  }
  else if (rule.get('type') === 'SYMMETRIC'){
    return new window.Handlebars.SafeString("<span style=\"color: lightgrey\">" + rule.get('id') + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong></strong>Rule " + rule.get('left') + " <strong>Symmetric Difference</strong> Rule " + rule.get('right'));
  }
  else if (rule.get('type') === 'INTERSECTION'){
        return new window.Handlebars.SafeString("<span style=\"color: lightgrey\">" + rule.get('id') + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong></strong>Rule " + rule.get('left') + " <strong>Intersection</strong> Rule " + rule.get('right'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you mind giving us an example of the json/model that's returned from your model hooks so we could build up an example and figure out what's not working properly?  I have a hunch it's related to your overriden renderTemplate and named outlets, but I'd just be guessing.

Comment: Hi kingpin2k, my apologies for leaving that out earlier. I really appreciate your help. I've edited the post, and added the relevant rest api responses. Hope this helps. Having some trouble getting the app into hosting (Java dinosaur, node newb), but it should run with 'grunt server' if cloned from Github (although, of course, the web service apis are not there. doh).

Comment: removed named outlets, still same

Comment: Just ran into one of these errors: `Uncaught Error: You cannot modify child views while in the inBuffer state ` and it is a very misleading error. For me it was because a Handlebars template output a (sublty) malformed HTML fragment. I know this question was answered a while ago, but I just had to vent - I'm not getting back the past couple of hours chasing the damn thing!

The error message made me hunt for logic errors in my controllers and routes. @kingpin2k Thanks for your answer below, suggesting it was due to malformed HTML, I would have never thought to check there.

Comment: Yeah, it's a beast to track down, but once you've wasted a day trying to track it down you never forget it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times I see this it's related to invalid HTML, mismatched divs/sections etc.

```
<section id="details">
{{outlet details}}
<section id="details">
```

should be

```
<section id="details">
{{outlet details}}
</section>
```

And in the plan.hbs `section` is misspelled as `secion`.

Additionally using the / as the concepts path seems to be confusing ember, it thinks that the url with the / at the end is still just refset (not concepts)

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('refsets', {path:'/'});
  this.resource('create',  {path:'/create'}, function(){});
  this.resource('refset',  {path:'/:publicId'}, function(){
    this.route('concepts',  {path:'concepts'});
    this.route('plan',  {path:'plan'});
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Kingpin2k, many thanks for spotting that. That takes care of one of my 2 errors, many thanks! Still have a problem with that cryptic ember error message when transitioning between subroutes....

Comment: I'll try to get something hosted, or perhaps mock the APIs and commit, so the app can be run standalone.

Comment: All of the errors under "Problem #2" :-) Got the app hosted on BitNami EC2 instance now, but web service not yet deployed... Will let you know: http://refset.sparklingideas.co.uk:8000 Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, app is now hosted here: http://refset.sparklingideas.co.uk:8000, web service APIs are up.

Comment: I know you tried removing the named outlets before, but can you try removing the named outlet again (changing it to outlet), and disabling the renderTemplate hooks on concepts and plans

Comment: or clone from git, points to live apis, so should all work: https://github.com/sparkling/snomed-refset

Comment: Thanks for setting up the gh, that made it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: Hi kingpin2k, many thanks for all your help, I very much appreciate it. Sorry, I should have got the github working before posting :-) Actually, the deployed code and github head has the named outlets removed, as you suggested (I've not updated the snippets in this question). Same problem... Thanks, though!

Comment: It looks like it didn't like the router either.